# Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a collection of properly ..

Tags: general-topology

let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a collection of closed connected subsets of $X$ that is simply ordered by proper inclusion. Then

\begin{equation*}
Y = \bigcap_{A \in \mathcal{A}} A 
\end{equation*}

is connected.

Follow the hint : *If $C \cup D$ is a separation of $Y$, then choose disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ of $X$ containing $C$ and $D$ respectively and show that:*

\begin{equation*}
\bigcap_{A \in \mathcal{A}} (A - (U \cup V))
\end{equation*}

*is not empty.*

I checked the proof and I'm quoting it:

> **Just follow the hint. $Y$ is closed. Therefore, both sets $C$ and $D$ are closed in $X$** . Since $X$ is compact, they are compact as well, and, by exercise 5, since $X$ is also Hausdorff, there are open and disjoint $U$ and $V$ containing them. $A−U−V$ are closed, nonempty (otherwise, since $U$ and $V$ are disjoint and both contain a point of $Y$ , there would be a separation of $A$ , which is connected) **and nested (here we use the fact that the initial sequence is nested, otherwise the result would not hold),** therefore, since $X$ is compact, the intersection is nonempty. That implies **that there is a point in $Y$ that is not in $U \cup V$ and, therefore, not in $C \cup D$** . Contradiction.

Bold parts are the parts I couldn't get

B1: Y is closed I get that, $C$ and $D$ are open in $Y$ (by definition of seperation). But that doesn't make $C$ and $D$ closed in $X$ ? By the subspace definition they are actually OPEN in $X$

B2: I don't know how that conclusion was reached.

B3 : Is $Y \subset U \cup V$ ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$U$ and $V$ are disjoint and open in $Y$ and $U \cup V = Y$. This is what a separation of a set/subspace is commonly defined as.
So $U$ is the complement of an open set in $Y$ so $U$ is closed in $Y$ and as $Y$ is closed in $X$, $U$ is also closed in $X$. The same reasoning holds for $V$.

The $A \in \mathcal{A}$ are nested,so the sets $A \setminus (U \cup V)$ (which your proof's notation denotes as $A - U - V$) are also nested, as we just remove a fixed set from a nested family. If $A_1, A_2 \in \mathcal{A}$ then $A_1 \subseteq A_2$ or $A_2 \subseteq A_1$ (def. of nested) and so  $A_1 \setminus (U \cup V) \subseteq A_2 \setminus (U \cup V)$ or vice versa, depending on which one was true. These sets $A \setminus (U \cup V)$ are non-empty, as $U \cup V = Y = \bigcap \mathcal{A} \subseteq A$, and if the difference were empty , $U$ and $V$ (intersected with $A$) would form a separation of $A$, which cannot happen, as $A$ is connected.